# Can I leave my friend my body if I die

Tags: death

So when I die I want my friend to keep my body parts in a jars and maybe make a mask out of my face or some thing like that. Can I do that? I’m only 17 so idk if my parents would have a say or if a will would even work for me being in parental control. Anyways thanks

Comment: I sincerely hope that you live long enough that the under 18 question is moot, by a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you live. In Washington, [RCW 68.50.110](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=68.50.110) requires that

> Except in cases of dissection provided for in RCW 68.50.100, and where
>   human remains are rightfully carried through or removed from the state
>   for the purpose of burial elsewhere, human remains lying within this
>   state, and the remains of any dissected body, after dissection, must
>   be decently buried, undergo cremation, alkaline hydrolysis, or natural
>   organic reduction within a reasonable time after death.

Per [RCW  68.50.130](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=68.50.130),

> Every person who performs a disposition of any human remains, except
>   as otherwise provided by law, in any place, except in a cemetery or a
>   building dedicated exclusively for religious purposes, is guilty of a
>   misdemeanor. Disposition of human remains following cremation,
>   alkaline hydrolysis, or natural organic reduction may also occur on
>   private property, with the consent of the property owner; and on
>   public or government lands or waters with the approval of the
>   government agency that has either jurisdiction or control, or both, of
>   the lands or waters.

So cutting the body up and sticking the bits in a jar is illegal, but cremating or dissolving it and keeping the remains in a jar is legal.

As for parental permission, [RCW 68.50.160](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=68.50.160) says that

> A person has the right to control the disposition of his or her own
>   remains without the predeath or postdeath consent of another person. A
>   valid written document expressing the decedent's wishes regarding the
>   place or method of disposition of his or her remains, signed by the
>   decedent in the presence of a witness, is sufficient legal
>   authorization for the procedures to be accomplished.

It does not require that the person be an adult.